# Get internal constructor in UWP

Tags: c#, reflection, uwp, getconstructor

How to get internal parametrized constructor in UWP.

Why there is no [such](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cs01xzbk(v=vs.110).aspx) overload in UWP?

```
var ctr = typeof(T).GetConstructor(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, 
                                   null, CallingConventions.HasThis, 
                                   new[] {typeof(IBuffer)}, null);
```

The only overload i can call in UWP is this

```
var ctr = typeof(T).GetConstructor(new[]{typeof(IBuffer)});
```

Which only gets public constructors. I need to get internal constructors of my classes with `IBuffer` parameter and cache them in delegate reference.

Comment: You beat me to it. I think you will need to wait for .net standard 2.0 for some of the reflection stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a GetConstructors method which I could use instead.

```
var ctor = typeof(T).GetConstructors(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
    .FirstOrDefault(c =>
        c.GetParameters()
            .Select(x => x.ParameterType)
            .SequenceEqual(new[] {typeof(IBuffer)}));

var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IBuffer), "param1");
var expr = Expression.New(ctor, param);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<IBuffer, T>>(expr, typeof(T).Name, new[] { param });
return lambda.Compile();
```